what did the person in.this video call another person?
At 6:12 in https://youtu.be/AXXu50lbdC8, what did he call Nate Silver? A cook, clerk, ...? What does it mean and how is it contrasted with some position in academia?

I’m voting to close this question because ELL is not a transcription service

...but he says the guy is a clerk

The young guy on the left is a dick; he says 'the criteria is...'. Maybe worth noting that British speakers pronounce 'clerk' the same way as 'clark'.

He defintely "clerk" (with American pronunciation, see Michael's comment above). In context it means he is an administrator or collector of data and implies that he is not competent to analyse the data.
